# Update data from custom UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have created a custom view cell from a list data source. (listOfNotes)
On each custom cells (notes), I update data for every single record, but I am missing how to update this record on parent View controller (listOfNotes).

I can see single record values are updated fine on UITableViewCell class but this does not update listOfNotes

Once records are updated I want to update the whole listOfNotes with the new values

I have read tons of post and documentation but it is not clear to me

Do I need to use unwind segue? 
How should this be done?

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Finally, I was able able to do it with delegations and protocol. This video was really helpful https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DBWu6TnhLeY

Answer (score 0):

You can use reference(should pointing to the same address) of the object, so the object which you have used for list, same you have to use during editing it as well. And on completion of editing just reload table or collection view!